# php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file?

Tags: php

I am getting parse error for the following code block

```
<? if(!empty($_SESSION['sess_sdrf_msg'])) { ?>
   <div class="col-md-12 text-center bottom-buffer"><span <? if($_SESSION['errorflag'] == "1"){?>class="error_msg"<?php }else{?>class="success_msg"<?php }?> style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['sess_sdrf_msg']; unset($_SESSION['errorflag']);unset($_SESSION['sess_sdrf_msg']);?></span>
</div>   
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Go through your whole file and see if you have an equal number of `{` and `}`. You might have missed an opening `{` somewhere in the file (the actual error could be anywhere.) I would also recommend to exclusively use `<?php` over `<?`. Short open tags has been disabled as default since a bunch of PHP versions back (except for the short hand for echo: `<?=` which always are enabled regardless of the setting.

Comment: You don't have to put all your code on one line. It's compiled on the server and cached. You don't need to minimize it like java script. It's not going to lower the computing load.